# Responsive SVG issue

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have set an SVG to be 100% width of its parent container, however when the parent container is scaled in a responsive way the SVG jolts in size as it tries to maintain its aspect ratio.

This is a problem when trying to align an SVG to a sibling DIV as in this example;

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 480 29.8">
<path style="fill:blue;" d="M480,29.8H0v-18C0,5.3,5.3,0,11.8,0h456.4c6.5,0,11.8,5.3,11.8,11.8L480,29.8L480,29.8z"/>
</svg>

<div class="rect" style="width:100%;background:red;height:100px;"></div>
```

As you can see when changing the width of the window, the DIV scales as expected, where the SVG jolts in size. 
**Updated Fiddle 14/03/16** https://jsfiddle.net/adotellison/euyyze4z/2/

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how to fix this issue?

I have seen this issue in web-kit browser.

Comment: Not seeing an issue in Chrome. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You might need to explain what the term "jolts in size" means :)

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle, giving the SVG a brighter colour so hopefully the problem will be more visible. By 'jolts in size' I mean the SVG, for a brief moment doesn't scale in size, and then suddenly jumps to its new dimensions. This happens in small increments, creating a jolting feel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SVG's partial-pixel positioning calculation being done differently than the other HTML elements.

The problem is only with the contents of the SVG.  If I put a CSS border on the SVG tag, the border remains the proper size, but the shapes inside wiggle when resizing.

I see the issue in Chrome, but not firefox in your jsfiddle, but if I put the SVG in a file and reference it as an image in the HTML I get the strange behavior in both.

I'm guessing this is just a bug and you can't really do anything to compeletly fix it.

You can add preserveAspectRatio="none" to the SVG tag. I think it's technically stretching it to fit the available space, but since it's only a pixel or two it's not noticeable.

I found that on this page: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/
This woman literally co-wrote the book on SVG: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032335.do

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution for this, as in the future I would like to use this technique for creating more complex shapes that CSS styles can't create. Can you think of any direction I should research in to find a solution?

Comment: I've just been playing around with a SVG Codepen example from CSS-Tricks and the SVG doesn't jump in size. Are they doing something different?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grwqoY

Comment: It does look better, but I think the problem is still there.  I think it might just be less noticeable because of the larger scale of the graphic. I added all your elements to the kiwi example and it was working good until I made the SVG viewbox the same size as your tab shape. 612-->480.  Then the wiggling came back.  Try increasing the scale two or three times of your graphic and see if that helps.

Comment: This fixes the issue in Chrome and Firefox, but it remains in Safari and Opera. Here's an updated Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grwqoY

Comment: I still had the issue in chrome 48.  It went away when I updated to 49.

Comment: I added  preserveAspectRatio="none" and it seems to fix it in Safari.  I think it's technically stretching it to fit the available space, bit since it's only a pixel or two it's not noticeable.  I found that on this page: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ This woman literally wrote the book on SVG.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is helping to hide the horrible effect. I'm going to thoroughly test this solution soon, so I'll let you know how I get on.